# How is the || operator used in CSS?

Tags: css, operators

CSS3 added the [<column-token>](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#column-token-diagram) operator as follow:

```
<column-token>: ||
```

It also says:

> <column-token> has been added, to keep Selectors parsing in single-token lookahead.

So, is that just an artifact of the lexer, or is that an actual operator used for something I do not know about yet?

Comment: I've never seen that on a stylesheet  `just an artifact of the lexer,`

Answer (score 1):

CSS level 4 does in fact have a [column operator](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-column-combinator) (used to select table cells of a column).

No idea if that's related and the token was added to CSS3 to be forward-compatile - it would be strange, but then the naming does not sound coincidental. The [argument](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2013Apr/0059.html) for the new token was indeed parsing convenience:

> I just added a COLUMN token to the Syntax draft, matching "||".  It's
>   needed for Selectors, so it can maintain LL(1).  (Otherwise, seeing
>   "*" followed by "|" is ambiguous until you look at the *next* token.)

Which I admit I don't quite understand. What else could `*|`  be interpreted as, even in CSS4? There is no other valid use of `|` in a selector (except inside an attribute matcher, but there there is no valid use for `||`). [CSS4 Values](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#comb-one) uses both `*`, `|` and `||` but that's not the spec the email was referring to.

Comment: FWIW the [latest CSS3 Syntax draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax/#token-diagrams) got rid of all the selector-related tokens.

Answer (score 0):

This is not strictly a CSS3 feature, column-token is just one of many tokens used to parse currently interpreted CSS stylesheet by CSS parser. So it has no use for you unless you're implementing a CSS parser.

Comment: I'm not too sure I follow you. I'm in fact implementing a CSS parser, similar to SASS but in C++. And in the grammar, I do not see the `<column-token>` being referenced.

Comment: SASS is a precompiler not a parser. This is just an operator used when a browser is paring CSS in order to render it.